# How can I add multiple icons to the Spark TabBar control?

Tags: apache-flex, icons, tabbar

In the MX TabBar component, the iconField property allowed us to display different icons in each tab.  In Spark, there does not seem to be an inherent way to add icons to the TabBar.  Does anyone have an example of implementing icon support for Spark's TabBar?  Is there a way to do this without extending the component?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hey after spending a week trying to follow multiple ways, (yours being top of the list) i found out a simpler and effective way to add icons to my tab bar, or any other component using skinning.

You dont need to create a custom component, just passing the icon and label through data.

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Tutorials_for_skinning_Spark_ButtonBar_component_w-16722.html

As personally, i was using content navigator with my tabbar/viewstack, i passed the icon as icon instead of imageicon. you can make changes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a skin for adding icons to Spark components; it is not as straightforward (IMHO) as Flex 3's MX components, though much more extensible.

Here are a few links which might help you get started:

- [Tour de Flex Tabbar examples](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/tourdeflex/web/#docIndex=0;illustIndex=1;sampleId=31160)
- [Custom Skin on Tabbar](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/10/10/creating-a-custom-skin-on-the-spark-tabbar-control-in-flex-4/)
- [Flex Tabbar with Skin](http://flex4fun.com/2010/08/24/flex4-tabbar-with-skin/)

Comment: Thanks much for the links.  I still don't see a way for the ButtonBarButton skin to be live to data passed into the TabBar component to render a different icon for each tab.  The Tour de Flex example uses a hard coded image.

Everything seems to point towards needing to extend TabBar in order to add icon support.  Has anyone done this?

I'm still wrapping my mind around the skinning architecture for Spark, but at the moment it seems that to achieve real reusability one must implement custom CSS styles or extend the component itself.

Can someone enlighten me otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've come up with a solution, which I'm posting below for posterity.  If anyone has a better way, I'd much appreciate the suggestion.

```
<!-- main app: TabBar implementation -->

<s:TabBar
    dataProvider="{contentTabBarPrimaryDP}"
    skinClass="skins.ContentTabBarSkin"/>

<!-- skins.ContentTabBarSkin: ItemRenderer implementation -->

<s:DataGroup id="dataGroup" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>

    <s:itemRenderer>
        <fx:Component>
            <custom:IconButtonBarButton
                label="{data.label}"
                icon="{data.icon}"
                skinClass="skins.ContentTabBarButtonSkin"/>
        </fx:Component>
    </s:itemRenderer>
</s:DataGroup>

<!-- skins.ContentTabBarButtonSkin: icon implementation -->

<s:HGroup       
    gap="3"
    paddingBottom="3"
    paddingLeft="3"
    paddingRight="3"
    paddingTop="3"
    verticalAlign="middle">

    <!--- layer 2: icon -->
    <s:BitmapImage id="iconDisplay"
        left="5"
        verticalCenter="0" />       

    <!--- layer 3: label -->
    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
        textAlign="center"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        maxDisplayedLines="1"
        horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1"
        left="10"
        right="10"
        top="2"
        bottom="2">
    </s:Label>

</s:HGroup>
```

This solution uses a custom DTO object for the TabBar dataProvider which stores the label text as well as the embedded icon image as a class.  I also had to extend the ButtonBarButton component to add an iconDisplay SkinPart, which looks like this:

```
[SkinPart(required="false")]
public var iconDisplay:BitmapImage;
```

This class also has getters/setters for the icon class property and sets the icon source, as such:

```
public function set icon(value:Class):void {

    _icon = value;

    if (iconDisplay != null)
        iconDisplay.source = _icon;

}

override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void {

    super.partAdded(partName, instance);

    if (icon !== null && instance == iconDisplay)
        iconDisplay.source = icon;      

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to be a bug/missed functionality of the your SDK version:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/552543
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-24331

Anyway, thanks for the solution with skins - very helpful