# Spark TabBar unique tabs

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, adobe, mxml

I currently have the following setup (abstracted for simplicity):

```
<s:TabBar id="extentTypeTabBar" dataProvider="{vs}"/>
<mx:ViewStack id="vs">
    <s:NavigatorContent id="firstTab" label="Action">
        <!--content-->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent id="secondTab" label="Adventure">
        <!--content-->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent id="thirdTab" label="Favorites">
        <!--content-->
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

I want thirdTab to have an image rather than a label (i.e. an image of a star or heart, instead of the word 'Favorites'). I've tried using the 'icon' property on the NavigatorContent, to no avail.

I believe to achieve this I'm going to have to create a custom skin with logic behind it for the Spark TabBar since I only want to uniquely skin one tab, not all tabs. Does anyone have an example of how to accomplish this?

Thanks!
jp

Comment: Does this help you? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452588/how-can-i-add-multiple-icons-to-the-spark-tabbar-control)

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine if you use the `icon` property of the `NavigatorContent` object. The `icon` property is typed as `Class`, so you have to provide it with the class that represents an embedded image or a FXG object.

Here is an example of both methods:

```
<s:NavigatorContent icon="@Embed('favorite_icon.png')" /> <!-- embedded icon -->
<s:NavigatorContent icon="{FxgAsset}" /> <!-- fxg asset -->
```

For convenience, I put the icon in the "default package" of my project, just change the path to the icon to match the location of your icon.  The FXG asset I'm using in the second example can be a located anywhere in your project. FXG assets are classes by nature, so you don't need to specify a path (your IDE should find it like any other class).

Note there are a few other ways to embed images, all of them should work ... the example I've shown here is the simplest :)